# Creating an RSS feed for Github Stars

Tags: github, rss

Is there some way to get an RSS feed for one's github stars list?

I want to get it into Pinboard via IFTTT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Github stars are available in JSON at a URL like this: https://api.github.com/users/username/starred (sub in your own username of course)

<s>I found [this Yahoo! Pipes thing](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=17f899d9ec26505fcf925ee920d1e024) to turn your stars into an RSS feed.</s>

The Yahoo Pipes service has shut down, and IFTTT apparently dropped the stars trigger from their Github channel.  So I went and created the same thing in my own [Huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn) instance, using a Website Agent and a Post Agent.

Comment: This works great with Zapier's web hook action, polling every 15 minutes and doing something with any new starred repositories that appear. (In my case, adding them to Pinboard.) FWIW the URL needs to be updated to <https://api.github.com/users/username/starred> (note HTTPS, not HTTP) then you're good to go!

Answer (score 9):

The current answer here gives the stars as JSON rather than RSS. Here's how I get my GitHub stars through the IFTTT RSS service:

1. Use the "New feed item matches" trigger
2. Enter your GitHub user RSS feed:

   ```
   https://github.com/csu.atom
   ```
3. Set the "Keyword or simple phrase" that IFTTT will use to match items to:

   ```
   [your username] starred
   ```

   For example, my filter is set to `csu starred` (the word "starred" alone would probably work, but then the trigger might also fire on some false positives, like if a repository name or something else includes the word "starred").
4. Add whatever action you want to happen whenever this trigger fires. The link to the starred repository is in the `{{EntryUrl}}` variable and the title is in `{{EntryTitle}}`.

Answer (score 1):

IFTTT now has this option. All you have to do [is create a recipe.](https://ifttt.com/myrecipes/personal/new)

Just put the "New Starred Repository" for THIS. And then do the appropriate steps for Pinboard for THAT.

**EDIT**

So apparently it might not work anymore, maybe, however on browsing the recipies I found [this](https://ifttt.com/recipes/71035-save-github-stars-in-pinboard), which probably does work so try it, just remember to edit it for your github username

Comment: That should work, but an RSS feed would be handy for those who don't use IFTTT but still want to get these in some other tool!

Comment: @JulienGenestoux: Yea it would, I'm just saying this steps because the op asked for IFTTT and Pinboard and Github

Comment: Doesn't seem to be enabled anymore.

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton not sure if it is or isnt (I don't personally use it) however if it isn't, there is https://ifttt.com/recipes/71035-save-github-stars-in-pinboard for IFTTT which I think works

Comment: FWIW, I don't see the "New Starred Repo..." trigger

Comment: @mghicks this answer was valid Jan 2014, its possible that there have been changes which removed the "New Starred Repo..."

Comment: Yahoo Pipes is shut down now as well, so the second option provided here will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

I've combined the SiftRSS service (https://siftrss.com/) with `https://github.com/username.atom` activity feed the OP mentioned. On SiftRSS I filter the activity feed with a `/\bstarred\s\w+\/\w+/` regex on the `title` attribute. Works flawlessly but is dependend on a third party service, if one needs to self-host, I would also recommend using [Huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn) as @larcher already mentioned.